# Whats is the best way to pull JSON Documents from Microsoft Azure and push into Kafka?

Tags: java, json, azure, apache-kafka, couchbase

I have like 150 TB of JSON documents which are stored on my Personal windows Driver. I am moving those drivers to Microsoft Azure Storage Account. I want to pull that JSON data and post it on Kafka. And from Kafka I want to push to Couchbase using Kafka-couch connector. Whats the best approach and procedure to do? (Keeping Replication of data in mind)

Azure  ---> Kafka ---> Couchbase

or Azure ---> Couchbase.

or Windows Drivers ---> Couchbase

Comment: Is this going to be done in Java? wondering why it is tagged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your needs, I offer you two alternatives.

The first option, in which you create your own programs to get data from Azure Blob Storage and push data to Kafka.You can use the `WebJob` to run it in Azure Web App Service.

This option is time-consuming, but it costs less.
You can refer to the snippet of code below or get more details of pushing data to kafka via java from [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+Producer+Example).

The second option ,in which you can use Azure HDInsight Service and follow the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage) to  access data stored in Azure Blob Storage via the syntax:
`wasb[s]://<containername>@<accountname>.blob.core.windows.net/<path>`.

Then , please download **`HDFS (Sink)`** Connectors on this [site](https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/) to push Json data to Kafka from HDInsight.

This option saves time, but it costs more.

You also could refer to the SO thread [Kafka Connector for Azure Blob Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877026/kafka-connector-for-azure-blob-storage) and just choose one of the two options according to your needs.

Hope it helps you.